# avoid the side effects of observeOn

Tags: java, rx-java2

I have written up a mock logic test below in order to mock the behavior that I am trying to create in our code. I noticed that in the test below, there appears to be some sort of lock on the emitter that occurs ONLY once you use the observeOn operator. The issue that this is creating for me is that it only emits the objects once the lock is released, and hits the subscriber with all of that work at once. The parallel real life case that this is affecting me is with creating a stream of stock quotes (mock stream and real stream). It waits until the queue of quotes (in observeOn i think) is filled up, and then nails our subscribers with 25,000 items at once it seems. We would like to use the observeOn operator, bc we have multiple subscribers and we dont want them all hogging the one subscribeOn thread. any suggestions?

```java
@Test
public void testObserveOnLogicOutsideCreate() {

    Observable.<AtomicInteger>create(numEmit -> {
        observableEmitter = numEmit;
    })
            .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribe(printNum -> {
                System.out.println(printNum);
                Assertions.assertTrue(nowObserveOnSwitchesOn);
                prevNum = printNum.get();
            });

    while (i < 10) {
        number.set(++i);
        observableEmitter.onNext(number);
        if (i == 10) {
            nowObserveOnSwitchesOn = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you using `Observable.create` instead of a `PublishSubject`? The test example by itself is flaky because the observer may just run in tandem with the test thread so the assertion could fail immediately. Also spinning up threads may take some time and with `Observable`, you may be generating a lot of items in that few milliseconds thus indeed, the whole consumer side after `observeOn` may just receive all queued up items right there. Please clarify your issue.

Comment: @akarnokd I've seen some comments about Subjects being unnecessary and somewhat controversial.  Have I been misled?

Comment: @akarnokd Sure no problem. This might be a little too case specific, but would very much appreciate the advice. I have one stream of stocks at the beginning, and I was hoping a quote would be emitted per flowableEmitter.onNext(quote). There are multiple subscribers to this Stream, and when we just used subscribeOn, it appeared to all be on oneThread. When we used osberveOn, it was on multiple threads, but there appeared to be a lock on emitter, and often information could be emitted even a few seconds after the original .onNext call. I was curious about this behavior and how to avoid it.

Comment: Publish subject does sound very much like what I want, but I to have been led away from it from comments I have seen (I do not think though it is relevant though to my oberveOn issue whether it is publish subject or not, although please correct me).

Comment: @akarnokd. I changed it to a publishSubject in the test above, and the same behavior happens. When the observeOn operator is there, 10 tens are printed and the test is true. When observeOn is not there, numbers 1-10 are printed (and test fails w/o removing the assertion). We are trying to have subscribers on separate threads while avoiding this. Is this possible?

Comment: If you have `Observable.create`, you'll get as many emitters as there are observers. If you store the emitter like in the example, you lose the previous emitters and they will hang. Also if you don't wait for the observer to finish in the test, the test completes early and you see success. The example you provided doesn't appear to be representative of your original issue; could you post a standalone project somewhere that demonstrates your problem more closely?